# primeng : trying to override p-tag styleclass, :host ::ng-deep doesn't work

Tags: angular, sass, primeng

Code is as below

**abc-component.html**

```
<td>
<p-tag styleClass = "p-mr-2" severity = "{{getSeverity(status)}}"
*ngIf = "status" [ngClass] = "status"></p-tag></td>
```

**abc-component.ts**

```
public getSeverity(status) {
  switch(status){
  'status1' : return "warning";
  'status2' : return "danger";
  'status3' : return "info";
  'status4' : return "primary";
  'status5' : return "success";
 }
}
```

**styles.scss**

```
:host ::ng-deep{
  .status6{
    color : blue;
    background : green; 
  }
}
```

I want status6 to have a custom color/background. But when I try to inspect my css in the browser, I notice that it takes color and background from p-tag class. ( I have verified that it's taking the status6 class, but it gets overridden by p-tag.)
How do I override the p-tag class?

Edit : After various failed attempts, I ended up using :not() with the other p-tag classes. :not() has higher specificity and was therefore applied successfully.

```
.p-tag:not(.p-tag-warning):not(.p-tag-success):not(...
```

Comment: It should be `:host` with single colon. See: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors

Comment: Typo, I manually copied it from my work laptop because I don't have SO access on it. I've corrected the post. <not resolved>

Comment: Hello, first, I would not want some method call in an expression, that would be called all the time, you might want to use a Pipe or Directive. Also, when you inspect element, what do you see in the selectors ? Maybe you can target your element better so it has priority. Last, check this article about extending Prime directives : https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/use-angular-directives-to-extend-components-that-you-dont-own#directives-that-load-data

Answer (score 0):

You must set styles with :host and ::ng-deep in something like "abc-component.scss" , not in global CSS file.

[Your's Example](https://angular-ivy-yptsmb.stackblitz.io)

Comment: I tried this, still didn't work. It;s still over ridden by p-tag